# symfony2, wordpress and nginx configuration

Tags: wordpress, symfony, nginx

I have symfony2 on the main page, now i tried to install WordPress on the sub directory called blog.
I'm using nginx as web server with fastcgi. I tried to configure the it but i got the error 500.
Does anyone know how to set it up properly on nginx?
Thanks

Comment: Please post your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^(.*) /app_dev.php last;
```

Should probably be something like

```
rewrite ^(.*) /web/app_dev.php last;
```

You also probably rather want to use try_files like so, else your images, css, js assets won't be found. Something like

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite       
    try_files $uri /web/$uri @rewrite;

    expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    location ~ \.php {
        expires off;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME                                      
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;         
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS              on;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://www.youtube.com/" ;
    }
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /web/app.php/$1 last;
}
location /blog {
   //Wordpress routing here
}
```

Anyway that is how I'm doing it with Magento instead of Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it didn't work well. Do you have idea about blog section?